# User to select certain numbers from prompt

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to make the user select certain numbers from a `prompt`, the empty input returns the `alert` message but I have no clue how to go about getting an `alert` message when the user chooses a number that is less than 8 or more than 128. Thank you!

```
var passwordLength = function () {
    //parseInt convert a string into an integer
    var charLength = parseInt(prompt("How many characters would you like your password to be? Please choose a number from (8-128)"));

    if (!(charLength > 8 || charLength < 128 || charLength === " ")) {
        alert("Please choose a number from (0-128)");
        return passwordLength();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional is messed up.

It needs to be either

```js
!(charLength > 8 || charLength < 128 || charLength !== "")
```

or

```js
(charLength < 8 || charLength > 128 || charLength === "")
```

Note also that, if anything, you'd need to use *empty* strings, not strings with a space in it. But I see no real reason for that: `parseInt` will either return a number or `NaN`, so, as LW001 suggests, you may want to use `isNaN` instead.

Comment: second one is much easier to read, it doesn't even need the parens around it either.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if (charLength < 8 || charLength > 128 || isNaN(charLength)) {
    alert("Please choose a number from (8-128)");
    return passwordLength();
}
```

Your condition was negated (!), removing that worked (Or you could flip the comparisons around). Also, for checking whether the input is not a number I'd recommend isNaN instead of checking against an empty string, you checked against a space by accident which could get awkward and be a pain to find.

Comment: Not only was the conditional negated, he was mixing valid and invalid conditions: `charLength > 8` and `charLength < 128` were expected to be true, `charLength === " "` (though nonsensical) was expected to be false. That's why it worked in some cases but not others.

Comment: Prob no need for that return statement either.

Comment: @DanZuzevich There is, in the question it's wrapped in a function (but it's hard to see because the indentation is messed up).

Comment: Still should work fine. I just tested it with no return and with your updated conditional. Seems good.

Comment: The isNaN is def clutch though, if you don't use that as the third check, you can enter something like 'a', and it will pass no problem.

Comment: @DanZuzevich You're right, since the function is recursive, really no need to have a return statement.